# How to clone a XML node, change value inside it and append it without changing all nodes with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom

I have a XML document where this particular node is retrieved using `xmldoc.find("main_node")`:

```
<main_node>
   <rule_node>
     <rule_name>Default_rule</rule_name>
   </rule_node>
</main_node>
```

I'm trying to clone the `<rule_node>` node, change the `<rule_name>` node value inside it and append it to `<main_node>` node after but I'm always changing all the `<rule_name>` nodes values.

I'm stocking the default `<rule_node>` node inside a variable name `rule_xml` and then performing the clone and value change like this:

```
for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
   $(rule_xml).clone().appendTo(sld.find("main_node")).find("rule_name").text("Rule_no" + (i+1))       
}
```

It results in this XML which is incorrect:

```
<main_node>
   <rule_node>
     <rule_name>Rule_no2</rule_name>
   </rule_node>
   <rule_node>
     <rule_name>Rule_no2</rule_name>
   </rule_node>
   <rule_node>
     <rule_name>Rule_no2</rule_name>
   </rule_node>
   <rule_node>
     <rule_name>Rule_no2</rule_name>
   </rule_node>
</main_node>
```

I tried using the children() function like this but it does not work:

```
$(rule_xml).clone().children().find("rule_name").text("new_text_here")
.appendTo(sld.find("main_node"))
```

**How can I change the `<rule_name>` node text of the cloned node only ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the result you have given, it looks like your current code is updating each rule_name element at every iteration.  However, it's a bit strange that they are all numbered two - I would expect them to all be numbered three (last iteration is 2, and rules are numbered i +1).  I've just tested your code and I can't replicate the issue.

Perhaps try this code and see if it works for you:

```
for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    //Clone the node
    var newNode = $(rule_xml).clone();
    //Update that individual node
    newNode.find("rule_name").text("Rule_no" + (i+1));
    //Now append that node
    newNode.appendTo(sld.find("main_node"))       
}
```

Comment: It looks like it was a visualisation bug from visual studio javascript debug console. I was looking at the updated "main_node" by typing "xml.find("main_node")[0]" and all the added nodes had the same rule_name. But when I left the debug session and try the same thing but with the IE debugger, the nodes had the correct "rule_name" values...

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out :)